# Selecting multiple elements including current

Tags: xslt

I have data structured like this:

```
<url title="Stack Overflow">http://stackoverflow.com/</url>
<url>http://example.com/</url>
```

The title attribute is optional. I have an XSLT stylesheet including this:

```
<xsl:template match="url">
    <a href="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="(@title | .)[1]"/></a>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to display the title if there is one and otherwise display the url. However for some reason the title is never displayed. (In every case the url is displayed.)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try either:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(@title | text())[1]"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(@title | .)[last()]"/>
```

**Explanation**:

The `.` abbreviation in your expression represents the `url` element itself, which precedes its attributes in document order.